# Registry key to stop removing HyperV after windows update

Tags: windows-10, windows-11, hyper-v, regedit

I have HyperV installed on Windows 11 Home. I know it's for `Pro` users only, but it can be installed on home as well.

#### Actual Behaviour

Every time there is a Windows update, hyperV gets removed and the corresponding VM's as well and feature is turned off.

#### Workaround Behaviour

##### Used it for more than a year now.

There used to be a registry key that I had set to stop this behaviour meaning even across any sort of updates or upgrades, HyperV was enabled and the VM's were still persistent.

#### Current Situation

A new Windows update (actually the recent 2 updates, which were insider previews) has wiped this key, so does anyone know what the key could be? Previous insider previews did not show this behaviour.

#### PS:

The key I'm looking for is in a way similar to `DoNotUpdateToEdgeWithChromium` in the case of Microsoft Edge, where this key would stop Edge from being installed every time there was a Windows Update, in case Edge was uninstalled already.

Comment: Can your question be summarized as "how to remain on a specific version of Windows 10"? There isn't a key that will prevent the removal of Hyper-V since the method you have used to install Hyper-V on Windows 10 Home is not actually supported.

Comment: I went ahead and flagged as a duplicate of two questions, with solutions, to what I believe will stop feature update from being installed which is likely the "updates" that cause your unofficial workaround to be reversed.

Comment: @Ramhound, well, this hack actually worked for more than a year now, and I have had many Windows updates (any insider update, feature upgrade, cumulative updates) and HyperV was persistent until now.

Comment: The reasons I voted to flag as a duplicate had less to do with the fact you are enabling Hyper-V on Windows 10 Home, and more to do with the fact, I strongly believe configuring Windows 10 NOT to install future feature updates will keep your unofficial workaround working. You indicated that "Every time there is a Windows update", which suggest you are repeating the unspecific process, weekly and even if that is the case the removal of Hyper-V shouldn't effect your Hyper-V VMs (just your ability to turn them on).

Comment: @Ramhound, I do know keeping Windows 10 from updating (specific updates) will keep the workaround, but the goal was to keep the workaround even with the updates, and it actually worked (really don't know how). I even did a win10 to win11 upgrade and still it worked.  When I meant `Every time there is a Windows update` I meant as of now (recent 2 or 3 updates) not the past ones, I guess that was really confusing, sorry.

Comment: Without better understanding how you enabled Hyper-V I cannot comment on the reason cumulative updates would disable Hyper-V.  I would only expect feature updates to disable it, for a varity of reason, but historically settings defaults were always redefined.

Comment: @Ramhound, I understand your point. Can you please look into the recent edit and unflag the question if possible?

Comment: You can use the solution in the duplicates to remain on a specific version, until the next stable feature update is released, this will allow you to keep receiving cumulative updates but staying on the same major version of Windows 11.  Since you are running an Insider Preview build of Windows 11 what you want is virtually impossible until 23H2 is released.

Comment: In the length of this post, you could have upgraded to Pro and moved on. I have Hyper-V running just fine in Windows 11 Insider Pro.